# cURL multiple links in the same time

Tags: bash, curl

I have the following command:

```
curl -XGET {url} -H "Referer: {ref}" -o data/{id}.txt
```

I wrote a python script that automatically runs it and saves the output in a specific directory. The bottleneck is that I can only process one file at a time.

What can I do to get multiple items in a single call?

Comment: Use `aria2` instead of writing your own solution.

Comment: curl 7.66.0 and later supports [-Z for parallel downloads](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/07/22/curl-goez-parallel/)